# Difference between spring @Controller and @RestController annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Difference between spring `@Controller` and `@RestController` annotation.

Can `@Controller` annotation be used for both Web MVC and REST applications?
If yes, how can we differentiate if it is Web MVC or REST application.

Comment: `@RestController` it is designed to follow the `REST architectural design`. As the main purpose of an `REST API` it is to provide only data to be processed by another application. Therefore, as explained below you can only send data cannot return a view.

Answer (score 557, accepted):

- `@Controller` is used to mark classes as Spring MVC Controller.
- `@RestController` is a convenience annotation that does nothing more than adding the `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations (see: [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html))

So the following two controller definitions should do the same

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class MyController { }

@RestController
public class MyRestController { }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35407390/restcontroller-without-responsebody-on-methods-work-incorrect

Comment: I think @RestController also converts the response to JSON/XML automatically.

Comment: Just sharing a link to a Spring tutorial explaining the difference https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Also if you use template engine like `Thymeleaf` it will not work with `@RestController` because of `@ResponseBody` which included in this annotation.

Comment: `@ResponseBody` makes the returned objects to something that could be in the body, e.g. JSON or XML ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647129/562769))

Comment: add @micha's words; There is a good explanation and an example in this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller

Comment: How does `@Controller` knows that it needs to get a view compared to `@RestController` which wraps responses in ResponseEntity?

Comment: @piepi If `@ResponseBody` is not present Spring tries to look up a view. With `@ResponseBody` (which is included with `@RestController`) Spring converts the objects returned by controller methods to the appropriate format based on Accept headers

Comment: `@Controller` - Available since 2.5 version of spring framework
`@RestController` - Available since 4.0 version of spring framework

Answer (score 88):

In the code below I'll show you the difference
between  `@controller`

```
@Controller
public class RestClassName{

  @RequestMapping(value={"/uri"})
  @ResponseBody
  public ObjectResponse functionRestName(){
      //...
      return instance;
   }
}
```

and `@RestController`

```
@RestController
public class RestClassName{

  @RequestMapping(value={"/uri"})
  public ObjectResponse functionRestName(){
      //...
      return instance;
   }
}
```

the  `@ResponseBody` is activated by default. You don't need to add it above the function signature.

Answer (score 48):

`@RestController` is the combination of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`.

Flow of request in a `@Controller` class without using a `@ResponseBody` annotation:

[image]

`@RestController` returns an object as response instead of view.

[image]

Answer (score 38):

If you use `@RestController` you cannot return a view (By using `Viewresolver` in Spring/springboot) and yes `@ResponseBody` is not needed in this case.

If you use `@Controller` you can return a view in Spring web MVC.

Comment: Yes, @ResponseBody can be put on a method and indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view name)

Answer (score 25):

`@RestController` annotated classes are the same as `@Controller` but the `@ResponseBody` on the handler methods are implied.

Comment: Excellent Article
https://www.genuitec.com/spring-frameworkrestcontroller-vs-controller/

Comment: Above article is really good. Thanks @Karan

Answer (score 16):

Actually, be careful - they are not exactly the same.

If you define any interceptors within your application, they will not apply to Controllers annotated as `@RestController`, however they do work with `@Controller` annotated controllers.

ie. configuration for the interceptor:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new TemplateMappingInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**", "/admin-functions**").excludePathPatterns("/login**");
    }

}
```

and in the declaration of a Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class AdminServiceController {...
```

Will work, however

```
@RestController
public class AdminServiceController {...
```

does not end up having the interceptor being associated with it.

Comment: `@RestController` was introduced in Spring 4x. This annotation is also annotated itself by `@Controller` so if it not working like an `@Controller` then report this as a bug.

Comment: @bertybro, that's not quite right. You can associate an `Interceptor` to a `@RestController`.

Comment: I've certainly successfully attached an `Interceptor` to a `@RestController`.

Comment: That would meant, above assumption is false? So certainly it would meant to only assist with implicit @ResponseBody annotation.

Answer (score 13):

`@Controller` returns `View`. `@RestController` returns `ResponseBody`.

Comment: You should explain more. How is this answering the question?

Comment: @Yunnosch  'view' is your front end like jsp or html. ResponseBody can be xml, json,yaml

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to add helpful information. However I still do not get how it should answer the question. Could you phrase an explanation like "Yes you can/No you cannot, because ...."?

Answer (score 11):

As you can see in Spring documentation ([Spring RestController Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html)) Rest Controller annotation is the same as Controller annotation, but assuming that `@ResponseBody` is active by default, so all the Java objects are serialized to JSON representation in the response body.

Answer (score 5):

THE new @RestController annotation in Spring4+, which marks the class as a controller where every method returns a domain object instead of a view. It’s shorthand for @Controller and @ResponseBody rolled together.

Answer (score 3):

`@Controller` is used in legacy systems which use JSPs. it can return views.
`@RestController` is to mark the controller is providing REST services with JSON response type. so it wraps `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotations together.

Answer (score 2):

`@RestController` was provided since Spring 4.0.1. [These controllers](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) indicate that here @RequestMapping methods assume @ResponseBody semantics by default.

In earlier versions the similar functionality could be achieved by using below:

1. `@RequestMapping` coupled with `@ResponseBody` like `@RequestMapping(value = "/abc", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces ="application/xml")
       public @ResponseBody MyBean fetch(){
    return new MyBean("hi")
    }`
2. `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` may be used as one of the ways for using JSON with  Jackson or xml.
3. MyBean can be defined like

`@XmlRootElement(name = "MyBean")
 @XmlType(propOrder = {"field2", "field1"})
    public class MyBean{
     field1
     field2 ..
    //getter, setter
    }`

4. `@ResponseBody` is treated as the view here among MVC and it is dispatched directly instead being dispatched from Dispatcher Servlet and the respective converters convert the response in the related format like text/html, application/xml, application/json .

However, the Restcontroller is already coupled with ResponseBody and the respective converters. Secondly, here, since instead of converting the responsebody, it is automatically converted to http response.

Answer (score 0):

- `@Controller`: This annotation is just a specialized version of `@Component` and it allows the controller classes to be auto-detected based on classpath scanning.
- `@RestController`: This annotation is a specialized version of `@Controller` which adds `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody` annotation automatically so we do not have to add `@ResponseBody` to our mapping methods.

Answer (score 0):

The @Controller annotation indicates that the class is a "Controller" like a web controller while @RestController annotation indicates that the class is a controller where @RequestMapping methods assume @ResponseBody semantics by default i.e. servicing REST API

Answer (score -3):

`@RestController` is composition of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`, if we are not using the `@ResponseBody` in Method signature then we need to use the `@Restcontroller`.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using @Controller and @ResponseBody, @RestController let's you expose Rest APIs in Spring 4.0 and above.

Comment: You want to say *I think @RestController also converts the response to JSON/XML automatically.* ? you used an abstract sentence instead of explain it clearly, I won't suggest that.

Comment: Come to think of it, @Controller does the same as it take hte produces and consumes mime types JSON/XML or otherwise...@ResponseBody  tells Controller to behave like REST endpoint without producing a View. RestController implicitly does that.