# Spring MVC - Request Return Value in Browser

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I imported the [Getting Started - Securing a Web Application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) in STS and added a controller for navigation, the request gets called and the return value instead of redirecting gets displayed in the browser. Any idea why it does this and how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
@RestController
public class BetController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String username(Model model) {
    System.out.println("Test");
    model.addAttribute("username", WebSecurityConfig.getUsername());
    return "statpage";
}
```

The page start page is registered in this manner:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("startpage");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}
```

All I get in the browser is a blank page with "startpage" on it, looking at the page's source there is no html just "startpage"

Comment: You have annotated your controller with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.

Comment: @RestController is just for convenience http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242321/difference-between-spring-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation

Comment: I strongly suggest you read up on what `@RestController` does as judging from what you are doing and your comment you are lacking that understanding. Trust me chancing it will make it work...

Comment: I tried switching '@RestController' to '@Controller' but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: There is also another issue with your code or at least how you expect it to work. You return the name of a view, this viewname is resolved to an actual view by a `ViewResolver`. What you have configured is that the `/` url will render a `startpage` view. I suspect that you get a 404 now in stead of `statpage` (which should be `startpage` I guess).

Comment: After I changed some view names and file names it made a difference and started working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning ModelAndView instead of a String in the RequestMapping method solved the problem:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView username(Model m) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("username", WebSecurityConfig.getUsername());
    mav.setViewName("betting");
    return mav;
}
```

Another solution is changing `@RestController` to `@Controller` and making sure all the names match