# what's wrong with my simple Spring web service?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-web

I built a simple Spring Web application.  I have this simple @Controller with an @RequestMapping, but when I run it I can't hit the URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/labutil/all
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.mycompany.ion.labutil.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.nokia.ion.labutil.service.LabService;

@Controller
public class LabController {

    @Autowired
    private LabService labService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAll() throws Exception {
        List<String> list = labService.getAll();

        // build fake little json formatted data
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("{");
        for (String s : list) {
            sb.append("{ "+s+" }, ");
        }
        sb.append("}");

        return sb.toString();
    }


}
```

Comment: can you also try http://localhost:8080/all ? it seems like an url issue to me.

Comment: Could you please post your application-context.xml file.

Comment: You're not setting `/labutil` anywhere in the controller. @Kael53 suggestion should work (perhaps adding the app context in the URL)

Comment: You need `@RestController`, not `@Controller`. Otherwise, the returned string is supposed to be a view name.

Comment: @Kael53 /all didn't work either.  The web app is running as http://localhost:8080/labutil ... when I go there I see the index.jsp that lives in the /src/main/webapp/index.jsp ... I assumed the URL would be /labutil/all

Comment: Check the logs to see if you didn't have any dependency error. Sometimes the app is deployed even if there are these kind of errors

Comment: As @SachinSarawgi mentioned, your configuration files will help us resolve the problem, from my observations , no error exists in this class.

Comment: You have the solution here, but in addition, "can't hit" is not a useful, specific description of the unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to annotate your controller as @RestController or add to your method the @ResponseBody annotation. This way you are telling Spring that this method returns the object as HTTP body response. The @RestController is a convenience annotation annotated with both, the @Controller and the @ResponseBody annotations.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646332/how-exactly-works-the-spring-responsebody-annotation-in-this-restful-applicatio) the answer why you should use this annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getAll() throws Exception {
    List<String> list = labService.getAll();

    // build fake little json formatted data
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("{");
    for (String s : list) {
        sb.append("{ "+s+" }, ");
    }
    sb.append("}");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

On the other hand, you should return an object, not a parsed String Json, add some Json library like Jackson or Gson and configure the View with the respective library view implementation.