# Best practice to send Json response from Spring controller methods

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I want to return a string (json string) from a spring controller as response to AJAX call it receives, the response could different based on whether or not I have a @Valid form submitted. This is how I am handling it and wanted to find out if this is considered as best practice? 
Please note I am using @RestController so @ResonseBody applies all methods.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveScheduledAlert(@Valid ScheduledAlertForm scheduledAlertForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        jsonString.append("{\"success\" : \"false\"");
        for(ObjectError error : bindingResult.getAllErrors())
            jsonString.append(",\"").append(((FieldError) error).getField()).append("\":\"").append(error.getDefaultMessage()).append("\"");
    } else {
        //save the data
        jsonString.append("{\"success\" : \"true\"");
    }

    jsonString.append("}");
    return jsonString.toString();


}
```

Comment: @ResponseBody annotation? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646332/how-exactly-works-the-spring-responsebody-annotation-in-this-restful-applicatio

Comment: I am using @RestController its a spring boot application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so basically what you want to do is generating 2 pojos

```
public class RestWrapperDTO {
    protected boolean success;
    public boolean isSuccess() {
        return success;
    }
    public void setSuccess(boolean value) {
        success = value
    }
}
```

and a another error DTO

```
public class RestErrorDTO extends RestWrapperDTO {
    private Map<String, String> errors;

    public Map<String, String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
    public void setErrors(Map<String, String> value) {
        errors = value
    }
}
```

and your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public RestWrapperDTO saveScheduledAlert(@Valid ScheduledAlertForm scheduledAlertForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();

    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        RestErrorDTO errorDTO = new RestErrorDTO();
        // fill map with errors here
        return errorDTO;
    } else {
        RestWrapperDTO wrapperDTO = new RestWrapperDTO();
        wrapperDTO.setSuccess(true);
        return wrapperDTO;
    }
}
```

it is not the most sufficient code, but it should help you :D

> if you are using a simple @Controller annotation - what you are
>   looking for is the `@ResponseBody`-annotation
>
> or if you use @RestController than this is already available
>
> You can simply return an object with the interface Serializable - a
>   simple POJO and spring will handle the rest.
>
> For further readings:
>
> - https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody
> - [How exactly works the Spring @ResponseBody annotation in this RESTful application example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646332/how-exactly-works-the-spring-responsebody-annotation-in-this-restful-applicatio)
> - For @RestController a minor explanation [Difference between spring @Controller and @RestController annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242321/difference-between-spring-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation)

Comment: I already have ResonseBody applied to all methods as I am using @RestController, futher more what I want to do is just return success : true if all went well or send the success : false and then validation errors as key value pairs in json thats all.

Comment: basically i have the explanation and @nick savenia the code example

Comment: my recommendation,

Comment: I thought of return Object previously but was wondering how would I send a success : false message to find out at client that something went wrong?

Comment: thanks, that makes sense but why should I not use just one class with a boolean flag and a Map for errors? wouldn't that be simple enough?

Comment: Yeah for your usecase yes... But what if you want to have more objects with that success flag

Comment: ok cool, I am mark your answer as correct answer to my question, one last question: is that the best "Spring way" of return json to ajax requests? or there is no standard way and it all depends on use cases?

Comment: in my opinion it is the best way to return json objects and it is the standard way for returning objects also for xml, there is an on XMLMessageConverter etc.

Comment: In ajax request e.g. JQuery ajax, the above controller method will always fall in success handler right? and based on success value of "success" I will render response, and the error handler of JQuery ajax will be for exceptions etc, is that right way of thinking about ajax success and failure handlers?

Answer (score 3):

Old question but for anyone else that needs help with this, I use a custom `ApiResponse` class for this. My class looks like this:

```
public class ApiResponse<T> {
    String message;
    int statusCode;
    T data

    //....getters and setters
```

This way, I can use "SUCCESS" or "ERROR" as the message, the appropriate `HttpStatus` code and then any Type as my data I want to send.

Then, in the controller, I just do this:

```
@PostMapping("/sign-up")
public ResponseEntity<String> signUp(@RequestBody Account account) {
  
  if (accountService.getAccountByEmail(account.getEmail()) != null) {
      ApiResponse<String> apiResponse = new ApiResponse<>("A user with that email  
          already exist", HttpStatus.CONFLICT.value(), null);
         return new ResponseEntity<String>(new Gson().toJson(apiResponse), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
  }

 // ... rest of controller code
```

As you can see, I use the `Gson` dependency to create my JSON String.

Answer (score 0):

create a POJO as given below:

```
public class SuccessPOJO{
private String success;

.....
getters and setters
.....
}
```

Now you can set values of success message and return this `SuccessPOJO` object. In the browser you will receive a `JSON` formatted object with success message!

Comment: yes but I want to send the validation errors too which can be variable in number, how would I send that?