# How to allow mapped fields in json response

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How to allow mapped fields in json response?

I have a entity with oneToMany mapping.

I am using spring boot. Want to return Whole object with mapped fields included in Json response created by @ResponseBody annotation.

Somehow  @ResponseBody annotation ignoring mapped fields.

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ResponseBody wont ignore any field until unless in hibernate or if you are using another ORM is being marked for lazy loading i.e lazy-loading=true , Kindly debug and check if those values are present in your entity object after Database retrieval

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646332/how-does-the-spring-responsebody-annotation-work-in-this-restful-application-ex   this may help you