# Custom HandlerAdapter for REST controllers in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

In my Spring Boot 2 project I use custom handler mapping and handler adapter to select the appropriate handler method. It works fine in case of simple Controllers. However, I don't know how to handle REST Controllers properly.

I mean the custom handler adapter implements the `HandlerAdapter`, that has a `handle` method with a return type of `ModelAndView`. But in case of a `RestController` I would like to return with a data object.

I can get it work as you can see below but it is an ugly solution and has problems when using with Spring `Projection`. In the code `MyResponseData` is a simple DTO I want to return in json format.

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");

    MyResponseData resp = fillResponse();

    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(resp);
        response.getWriter().append(json);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

How can I just simply return my data represented by the `MyResponseData` DTO?

Answer (score 0):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Demo1Application {

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Student> getStudent() {

      Student stu = new Student();
      return new ResponseEntity<>(stu, HttpStatus.OK);
   }
}
```

@RestController will automatically make the method return that object. Default will be json if the jackson library is found in the classpath

Comment: You might be able to get away with just using [@Responsebody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646332/how-does-the-spring-responsebody-annotation-work-in-this-restful-application-ex)

Comment: In this simple case it is true. But I have a custom mapping and a custom handler adapter where I have to implement Spring's `HandlerAdapter` with a `handle` method that returns a `ModelAndView`