# Flink JDBC connect for multiple tenant

Tags: java, hashmap, apache-flink

I have following 2 classes. The primary class is **Aloscalculation**, which has a variable **finalOutput** which contains certain values.`DataSet<Tuple4<String, String, Double, String>> finalOutput`. The value is tried to be inserted into postgresql. The variable connectionValues is having the json and it has various parameters like username,password,drivername which is received from a hashmap called outermap. From Writealos I am able to send the row object which is tried to be inserted in in Aloscalculation. But I am unable to send variable connectionvalues to set the drivername,password,url, and username. Please suggest me how to do it. The values like org_metric_result, org_metric_orgid are calculated accordingly.

I have now edited the code in a new way to solve the problem. But now the new issue is in Writealos method if the match doesnt takes place i get an empty object returned. Due which while Database insertion i get an exception saying Null value is being formed and cannot be inserted. Please anyone can solve this error?

```
    public class Writealos implements MapFunction<Tuple4<String, String, Double, String>, Row> 
    {
        @Autowired
        private Tenantresource outermap;
        public Row map(Tuple4<String, String, Double, String> arg0)throws Exception
        {
            if(arg0.f0.equals(currentKey))
            {
               Row obj = new Row(7);
               String string = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(32);
               obj.setField(0, string);
               obj.setField(1, alos);
               obj.setField(2, org_metric_result.toString());
               obj.setField(3, Start_Date.toString());
               obj.setField(4, End_Date.toString());
               obj.setField(5, Execution_Date.toString());
               obj.setField(6, org_metric_orgid);
         }
            return obj; 
        }
    }

    public class Aloscalculation
    {
        @Autowired
    private static Tenantresource outermap;
        public static void calculateAlos(Fhirresource fhir_resource ) throws Exception 
        {
            String query = "insert into reports (org_metric_id,org_metric_topic, org_metric_result, org_metric_from, org_metric_to, org_metric_executed_on, org_metric_orgid) values (?,?,cast(? as json),cast(? as timestamp),cast(? as timestamp),cast(? as timestamp),?)";
         for(String currentKey : outermap.tenantresourcereturn().keySet()) 
         { 
             JSONObject connection =new JSONObject( outermap.tenantresourcereturn().get(currentKey));
             System.out.println(currentKey);
             String url=connection.getString("jdbc_url")+":"+connection.getString("port")+"/"+connection.getString("db_name");
             System.out.println(url);
            finaloutput.map(new Writealos(fhir_resource,currentKey))
                .output(JDBCOutputFormat.buildJDBCOutputFormat()
                .setDrivername()
                .setDBUrl()
                .setUsername()
                .setPassword()
                .setQuery(query)
                .finish());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any idea regarding this anyone?

Answer (score 0):

How are you exposing  `public Row map(Tuple4<String, String, Double, String> arg0)`, is it through a service. Spring provides an annotation @`ResponseBody`. You need to have a matching POJO and spring will take care of the conversion. Secondly, why are you not planning to use any ORM tool (Hibernate, Ibatis etc), it can ease your CRUD operations.

[How does the Spring @ResponseBody annotation work in this RESTful application example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28646332/how-does-the-spring-responsebody-annotation-work-in-this-restful-application-ex)

Comment: `public Row map(Tuple4<String, String, Double, String> arg0)` is actually supported by flink and that is how the data in data set can be mapped in Rows.