# Make Api available as Restful Service

Tags: spring

I am trying to make our apis available as restful service.

Defined a controller with @Controller and inside defined a method as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/empDetails/{empName}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void getUserData(@PathVariable("empName") String empName, Model model) {
}
```

Does the above makes the api as Restful ???

In Simple just giving annotation makes the method as Restful API???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make it **RESTFul API** by returning an **object**, usually a *JSON*, rather than using **MVC**.

For your own convenience you could use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`.
You can learn about the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242321/difference-between-spring-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation).

Just an advice, depending on your snippet, when you use *GET* methods, return a *JSON* rather than `void`.

You can see a spring REST [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) (ignore the `spring boot` part).

And you could also see a spring MVC [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

I hope the differences will give you a clear point of view