# @RestController without @ResponseBody on methods work incorrect

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, controller

I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/base/url")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/child/url",
            method = RequestMethod.POST
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public String mmm() {      
        return "Ok";
    }
}
```

Now its working(server response `Ok`) but I thought that `@ResponseBody` redundant because we use `@RestController` and removed @ResponseBody annotation

and I see following server response:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
        <title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /base/url/child/url/Ok. Reason:

            <pre>    Not Found</pre>
        </p>
        <hr />
        <i>
            <small>Powered by Jetty://</small>
        </i>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>                                                


    </body>
</html>
```

Can you explain this behaviour ?

### P.S.

Spring version: `4.1.6.RELEASE`

P.S.

I have found only this part related to mvc config:

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="base.package"/>
```

Comment: that's interesting. seems like @RestController is not bypassing viewResolver

Comment: I did face the same issue yesterday! Only resolved when I included a `viewResolver` and a redundant `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Comment: Make sure you're not invoking `/base/url/child/url/Ok` but `/base/url/child/url`

Comment: @jfcorugedo I am absolutely sure

Comment: Mmm, have you seen that error: `Problem accessing /base/url/child/url/Ok`?  It seems that the URL ends with Ok

Comment: @jfcorugedo it means that spring tries to find view by this URL. If to add ResponseBody annotation - all works properly

Comment: @gstackoverflow btw, have you included StringHttpMessageConverter?

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. Are you using spring-boot or just spring mvc?

Comment: Post your configuration... Make sure you have `@EnableWebMvc` or `<mvc:annotation-driven />` else it won't work. If you have those make sure you don't have `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and/or `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` in your configuration.

Comment: @jfcorugedo just spring-mvc

Comment: I have an application with thymeleaf templating and rest controllers and it works using only @RestController. Can you post your MVC configuration?

Comment: That isn't mvc related. If there is no `<mvc:annotation-driven />` you are using the old deprecated classes... Add '<mvc:annotation-driven />` to enable the new classes which do support `@RestController`. The old ones don't and will treat `@RestController` as `@Controller`.

Comment: @M. Deinum now it is working after adding <mvc:annotation-driven />

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be able to use `@RestController` you have to explicitly enable the new annotation processing classes. By either adding `<mvc:annotation-driven />` (for XML) or `@EnableWebMvc` (for Java Config).

By default the `DispatcherServlet` registers the, now deprecated, `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` which can be considered the predecessor or the newer stuff.

Comment: Thanks. I refactored all my JSPs into Groovy templates (returned as response body) and was wondering why it is still looking for JSPs. It took me a while to find this answer. A lot of people are confused making the same switch or simply implementing REST. Your answer should be ranked higher to easily find it.