# 400 Bad request or 415 Unsupported Media type in Ajax post call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I have created a POST rest controller in spring. I want to call this controller from a ajax call.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAdzAcrVehicle")
@RestController("AdzoneAcrVehicle")
public class AdzoneAcrVehicleController {

private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AdzoneAcrVehicleController.class.getName());

private String jsonresponse;
@Autowired
@Qualifier(value="AzoneAcrVehicleService")
private AzoneAcrVehicle azoneAcrVehicle;
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getAll(@RequestBody ObjectNode json) {
       System.out.println(json);
    return json.get("vehicle").asText();
}
}
```

I am trying to call that rest controller by using all below provided solutions, But I am getting 400 Bad request or 415 Unsupported Media type error.

1)

```
var parameter = JSON.stringify({vehicle:datas[3]});
                 $.ajax({
                        url: appName+'/getAdzAcrVehicle',
                        type: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                           console.log(data);
                        },
                        data: parameter
                    });
```

2)

```
                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: appName+'/getAdzAcrVehicle',
                    data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Problem seems to be in `return type` as it is plain text. Try returning in JSON format `{key:value}` format.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is `@RestController` then `@ResponseBody` is not required. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25242458/6677551

You can specify the content type.

```
var parameter = JSON.stringify({vehicle:datas[3]});
    $.ajax({
            url: appName+'/getAdzAcrVehicle',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
            success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
            },
            data: parameter
      });
```

Comment: i have updated my ajax call to your code, now my controller is getting called and it's returning value. but, I am not getting any response in my browser console.What's the new issue now???Why this success: function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
            } is not executing ???

Comment: change return type from **String**,as it is expecting json result.

Answer (score 0):

You  forgot the responseBody in your method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String getAll(@RequestBody ObjectNode json) {
       System.out.println(json);
    return json.get("vehicle").asText();
}
```

Comment: I have added @ResponseBody too. But I am not getting any response in my browser console....