# Controller doesn't return html file

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

So I got this simple code I'd like to test but somehow it doesn't return the `dataBaseEntity.html`.

```
@Controller
public class DataBaseMicroserviceRestConnectorProvider {

    @Autowired
    private DataBaseSpringDataConnectorRequester dataBaseSpringDataConnectorRequester;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)                                 
    public String addNewDataBaseEntityForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("dataBaseEntity", new DataBaseEntity());
        return "dataBaseEntity";
    }
```

The `html file` is allocated in `src/main/resources/templates/dataBaseEntity.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/dataBaseEntity}" th:object="${dataBaseEntity}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And I got a second question: is there a way to do this with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`?

Comment: Is it spring-boot or just spring? In the latter case, please show your viewResolver configuration

Comment: It's spring-boot

Comment: Have you got the spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf dependency?

Comment: How are you trying to access the HTML form and what result do you currently get?

Answer (score 0):

[handle form submission in spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

go to this link, it will help to solve your problem.

there can be many things you may be missing in your example,

like :- I can't see your **dataBaseEntity** request in your controller , may be there you are missing something.

```
@RestController
```

we usually use for our rest end point not for jsp request.
hope by this link you will get your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a wrong configuration, please make sure you have set the right suffix and prefix for your templates:

```
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

If you don't have a config right now, this might be your problem, please refer to: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html

For your second question about the @RestController annotation. This is basically the same as writing: @Controller and @ResponseBody

See:
[Difference between spring @Controller and @RestController annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242321/difference-between-spring-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation)