# Redirect just displaying link instead of taking user to link

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is the controller method which i'm trying to redirect from:

```
@GetMapping("/opensignup/{id}")
public String openSignUp(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long Id) {

    Tournament comp = tournamentRepository.findOne(Id);
    boolean b = true;
    comp.setSignUpOpen(b);

    return "redirect:/comp/" + Id;
}
```

I have another method (which is a post, if thats relevant) which successfully redirects to the correct page/controller with the same line:

```
   return "redirect:/comp/" + Id;
```

Instead of redirecting, it simply prints that link on the browser. (It prints it with the correct id.) Like this:

redirect:/comp/5

How do I get it to redirect instead of print?

Comment: Do you have a `@ResponseBody` annotation somewhere in your second called method?

Comment: since you mento a browser, you can do it with JS. just catch the response and open it like `location.href= link`, if will post ans if you need after this

Comment: @BennettDams no, but I just realised where I said it worked before the class has a @ conntroller annotation, but in this class it had @ RestController annotation. Could this be causing it?

Comment: @Lucia Yes, I'll post an answer asap.

Comment: @BennettDams It turns out the @ RestController was causing it, thanks.

Comment: Very gracious of you to spare me the downvote, magnanimous friend. I found no stack over flow questions with the same problem. I Quadruple checked the syntax of " return "redirect:/comp/" + Id;" compared to other stack over flow answers with similar redirects, I didn't see any point in linking to those since the syntax was correct. If referring to those would have helped someone answer my question, then my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your second method is annotated with `@RestController`. While `@Controller` is meant to return views in the Spring context, `@RestController` is meant to return something that will be written to the response body directly (JSON in most cases).

`@RestController` is basically a combination of the `@Controller` **AND** a `@ResponseBody` annotation, whereby the second will try to map the POJO to JSON.

Further reading:

https://www.genuitec.com/spring-frameworkrestcontroller-vs-controller/

[Difference between spring @Controller and @RestController annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242321/difference-between-spring-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because the top of my method had an @RestController annotation instead of @Controller. Since I don't need it to be restful, I changed it and my problem is solved. If anyone wants to shed some light on why this is and/or how you would do it while keeping the @RestController annotation (if possible) then feel free.