# Spring Boot HTML page not rendering

Tags: spring-boot

I am in the process of learning Spring Boot and became unstuck when trying to post model data to an HTML file.

I have a controller, where I populate the model and call an HTML page from. When I put a breakpoint inside this method, the model data gets populated correctly, but the HTML page is rendered with only the name of the HTML file, and nothing else (no browser errors either). I am thinking it may have something to the with the file structure, and the fact that my RestController already has a path specified (because when I create a clean new controller with no explicit class-based @RequestMapping specified and call the template from the root path + name of HTML file, it renders correctly). I do have the ThymeLeaf dependency installed, and "userView.html" is placed inside the "template" directory.

ReaderController.java extract:

```
@RequestMapping("/reader")
public class ReaderController {

...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userView")
    public String getUser(Model model) {
        // business logic goes here
        model.addAttribute("userName","Somebody");
        model.addAttribute("url", "www.example.com");
        return "userView";
    }
```

userView.html extract:

```
<body>
<h1>User Data</h1>
  <p th:text="'Username: ' + ${userName}"/>
  <p th:text="'Url: ' + ${url}"/>
</body>
```

`http://localhost:8080/reader/userView` only renders the word "userView".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to the issue. I inadvertently used the @RestController annotation instead of the @Controller annotation to the controller class. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242321/difference-between-spring-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation) helps to explain the issue.