# @RestController does not return html with model

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to implement Spring boot MVC application with rest and Thymeleaf.
In my controller class I have something like below:

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private GetUserInfoSrv userSrv;;
    
    @RequestMapping("/") **OR** @GetMapping
    public String getAllUsers(Model model) {
    
    List<UserRep> listUser = userSrv.getAllUsersSvc(); //this is returning correct output
    model.addAttribute("userList", listUser);
    return "Index";
}
```

I am not getting the values populated in `Index.html`:

```html
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="users : ${userList}">
        <td th:text="${users.id}" />
        <td th:text="${users.firstName}">First Name</td>
        <td th:text="${users.lastName}">Last Name</td>
        <td th:text="${users.email}">Email Id</td>
        </td> -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

If I use `@Controller` annotation instead of `@RestController`, I am able to view the results on page. Any reason why `@RestController` does not work? I tried adding `@RequestMapping` / `@GetMapping` at class level as well as method level in `@RestController` but nothing works.

Answer (score 1):

**Restcontroller = Controller + ResponseBody**

So if you put response controller then it will send the data in response body.

So use controller annotation instead if you want to return a web page.

See [difference between controller and restcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25242321/6572971)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {
    // ...
}
```

by

```java
@Controller
public class UserController {
    //...
}
```

For easy-to-understand, generally, `@RestController` for generate RESTful API, `@Controller` for Spring MVC with form binding.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That is why I was wondering why I get 'TemplateInputException' when calling a REST (via postman) returning entity/representation object instead of template.