# When to use @Controller and when @RestController annotation in RESTApi based on Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am new to learning Spring and I created a simple RestApi. Now in some tutorials I see that the controller class is sometimes annotated with @Controller and others are annotated with @RestController.

Can anyone clarify the differences for me? Thanks

Comment: Another major difference is If you annotate RestController your method response automatically converted into Json format. Controller you have to define the response type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only took one quick google search for me to get a lot of answers.
Also, this question has already been answered in another SO thread, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242321/difference-between-spring-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation).

But quickly summarized:

`@Controller` is used to annotate your controller class.
When using `@Controller` you typically use it in combination with `@ResponseBody`. So you annotate your endpoint methods with `@ResponseBody` to let Spring know what return type to expect from that particular endpoint.

```
@Controller
public ControllerClass {

   @GetMapping("/greetings")
   @ResponseBody
   private String someEndpoint(){
       return "hey";
   }

}
```

`@RestController` simply combines `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`. So you don't need to annotate your endpoint methods with `@ResponseBody`. A single anntoation of your controller class will do the magic. The return type of the endpoint methods are used as response body.

```
@RestController
public ControllerClass {

   @GetMapping("/greetings")
   private String someEndpoint(){
       return "hey";
   }

}
```