Why does Spring Security FilterChain process @Controller and @RestController requests differently
I have a Spring OAuth2-Client with the following filterChain:
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> {
                    authorize.requestMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll();
                    authorize.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .build();
    }

and I have a controller with the following 2 endpoints:
@GetMapping("home")
public String home(){
    return "home.html"
}


@GetMapping("securedHome")
public String securedHome(){
    return "securedHome.html";
}

If I use @RestController annotation on this, Spring security works as intended. I'm able to get to /home and it'll return me a string with value "home.html", and if i go to /securedHome, it redirects me to login page, and I can see the page after I login.
If, however, I use @Controller annotation, Spring Security redirects me to login page when I try to go to /home, even though in my filterChain I have permitAll() on this request.
I'm trying to understand why this is, and am lost. I've tried to look at the documentation and search for answers, but unable to find it.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25242458/7068014

I think you have to add html page path to permitAll.

@kushparsaniya Yes, that seemed to work. Seems like there is an additional layer of security for views and we need to configure access to those as well

If you use @RestController you cannot return a view (By using Viewresolver in Spring/springboot) and yes @ResponseBody is not needed in this case. that's why when you tap /home it returns a string.
If you use @Controller you can return a view in Spring web MVC.
